# Can I use PDO to run multiple SQL queries and retrieve the number of rows affected for each statement?

Tags: php, pdo

Here's what I've got so far:

```
/**
 * @param PDO $db
 * @param string $file
 */
function run_sql_file($db, $file) {
    $sql = file_get_contents($file);
    try {
        $affected = $db->exec($sql);
        println("$affected row(s) affected");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        exitmsg($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

It does seem to run all the queries, but it always give me back "0 rows affected". Is there a way to get the number of rows affected for each statement? Preferably along with the associated query, and any error messages and warnings.

Comment: `exec` doesn't return the number of rows affected from a SELECT - what statements are you passing in?

Comment: @andrewsi: inserts, deletes, and truncates. "0" or something is fine for anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue, for example I am reading a series of mysql drop table sqls from a file and I want to execute them into a single PDO->exec():

```
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=test;dbname=db1', 'user', 'pass');
  try {

    $dbh->exec('drop table test_table1;drop table test_table2;');
  }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

If the first drop sql is successful then no Exception is rised even if the second one failed(that table name doesn't exist anymore). It seems there is no way you can check wether all of the sqls were executed or not with `PDO_MYSQLND;` only if the first one fails then a PDO Exception is rised.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the count variable after the execution:

$db->exec($sql);

$affected = $db->rowCount();

Comment: I'll bet this returns the count for either the first or last statement, not the total of all of them. PDO doesn't seem to support multiple statements officially. If you switch to mysqli, you can use `mysqli_multi_query`.

Comment: @Barmar: I was using `mysqli` for a bit, but I don't like the way it binds params and stuff.

Comment: Well, life is a series of tradeoffs. mysqli has multi-query, PDO has nicer binding.

Answer (score -1):

making the assumption that you don't have any crazy SQL that will blow up the explode statement...

```
/**
 * @param PDO $db
 * @param string $file
 */
function run_sql_file($db, $file) {
    $sql = file_get_contents($file);
    $sql_lines = explode(';',$sql);
    try {
        foreach($sql_lines as $line) {
            $affected += $db->exec($line);
        }
        println("$affected row(s) affected");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        exitmsg($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah... I don't like that assumption ;) Semi-colons are perfectly legal in strings.

Comment: this is crazy, strings may contain lots of semicolons

Comment: This could be dangerous. Splitting on ';' could break data inside SQL queries